# Interface methods are not recognized when declaring parent class

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract

it is quite hard for me to title this Thread. Feel free to fix this.

But here is my problem
I have a abstract class and a parent that extends from the abstract class.
I want one of the parents to have 2 more methods and call them in the Main Class.
I thought about using an Interface to solve this but this does not work.

Here is the scenario:

My Abstract class

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {

    public abstract void method1();
}
```

My Interface for the parent class

```
public interface IInterface {
    void method2();
}
```

My Parent Class

```
public class ParentClass extends AbstractClass implements IInterface{

    @Override
    public void method1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    //This is the additional method i want to use
    public void method2() {
    
    }
}
```

My Main Class

```
public class MainClass {

static AbstractClass a;
static boolean condition = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        if(condition) {
            a = new ParentClass(); // This class should contain the additional method
        }
        else{
            a = new AnotherParentClass();
        }

        a.method2(); <- This does not work. There is only method1()
    }

}
```

How do i accomplish this kind of Structure?
The Abstract class has only the basis of the parent class.
But i also want to give a parent class extra abilities but want to work with the Abstract class in the main so i dont have to create multiple isntances of a class.

Any tips are appreciated

regards
Nuri

Answer (score 0):

`a` is statically typed `AbstractClass` and thus you see only its methods.  The compiler cannot know that the runtime type has any other methods.

Suppose you declared another class `ParentClass3 extends AbstractClass` that did not implement `IInterface`?

The only solution is to cast to `IInterface` at the point of reference.  Then at runtime it will either invoke the method (if the object is the correct type) or throw `ClassCastException`.